# How to identify which layout xml is running currently?

Tags: android, android-layout, setcontentview

I have to layout xml named activity_layout_1 and activity_layout_2 and one common Activity.
Based on different conditions, I set contentview of the two xml
In a case, I need to check which layout is currently set.

I can get the id as below:

```
View currentView = this.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        int id = currentView.getId();
```

Is there a better way to get/identify current layout running?

Answer (score 1):

That id is the id of android.R.id.content no the id of the current layout.
A better way of doing is with tags `setTag()` and `getTag()`

Like:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
view.setTag(R.layout.fragment)
```